# If $f$ is identically zero then the coefficients are all zero

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

I am looking at the space:
$$A:=\left\{f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}{a_ne^{inx}}:(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\in l^1(\mathbb{Z})\right\}$$
I want to say the following: if $f\equiv0$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In my opinion, we can solve this problem with the information that $(e^{inx})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a basis for $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, but may you conclude the above result directly form this fact? If not, how do you go further?

Comment: Yes, you just need the fact that $$ a_m = \langle f, e^{imx} \rangle $$

Comment: And since $f=0$ also $a_m=0$?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know that $e^{inx}$ form a basis:   the completeness part of the basis definition is irrelevant here. The orthogonality of the exponential functions quickly leads to conclusion. Indeed, fix $m\in\mathbb Z$. For every $k\ge |m|$ we have
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-imx}\sum_{|n|\le k} a_n e^{inx} \,dx =  
\sum_{|n|\le k}a_n \int_0^{2\pi}  e^{i(n-m)x} \,dx = 2\pi a_m \tag{1}$$
(I truncated the sum by $|n|\le k$ to make it finite, so that there is no doubt about the legality of exchanging the order if integration and summation. Just trying to use a minimum theory here.)

The sequence $g_k(x) = e^{-imx}\sum_{|n|\le k} a_n e^{inx}$ converges to $e^{-imx}f(x)=0$ in $L^1(0,2\pi)$  because 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f-g_k| \le 2\pi \sum_{|n|>k}|a_n| \to 0$$ as $k\to\infty$. Thus, the left side of (1) tends to $0$ as $k\to\infty$. But since it's  equal to a fixed number $a_m$, it follows that $a_m=0$.